# moving image left to right javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate

So I need help, I need to create a javascript file (with matching HTML), that allows an image to move from left to right continuously. And then when the user clicks the mouse button, the image must then move up and down continuously.

I so far I have tried to do the first part, however using a code I have found that it does not work for me and I'm not too sure why.  I feel like I'm missing something so obvious but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code

**HTML**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Task 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="task2.css">
<script src="task2.js"></script>

<div id="animate">Sample</div>
</head>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
#animate {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
(document).ready(function() {
    var width = (document).width();

    function goRight() {
        ("#animate").animate({
        left: width
      }, 5000, function() {
         setTimeout(goLeft, 50);
      });
    }
    function goLeft() {
        ("#animate").animate({
        left: 0
      }, 5000, function() {
         setTimeout(goRight, 50);
      });
    }

    setTimeout(goRight, 50);
});
```

Comment: it doesn't accept them, console comes back saying undefined identifier or similar errors, is this because i've saved it as a .js?

Comment: you will need to load the jquery library as well.

Comment: how do i add the library? im sorry im quite new to javascript

Comment: Intro to jQuery, from jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a handler on click on image and funcs to updown:

```
    function goUp() {
    $("#animate").animate({
    top: 0
  }, 5000, function() {
     setTimeout(goDown, 50);
  });
}
function goDown() {
    $("#animate").animate({
    top: height
  }, 5000, function() {
     setTimeout(goUp, 50);
  });
}
$("#animate").on('click',function(){$('#animate').stop();
              if(upleft == 0)
              {goDown(); upleft=1;}
                                else {goLeft();upleft=0}
})
```

[FIDDLEEXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qVewK/)

Comment: im not sure why but the click function isnt working, it'll work in fiddle perfectly but not when i implement it?

Comment: i think you need to add the jquery script, for using animate function http://jquery.com/

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i've used <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: oh, also you need to wrap it into document.onLoad. In fiddle in the left menu you can chose where to insert the script, if it just in head, then there is no element when script execute, so we need to execute it when document is loaded.